# Rosmake openni_camera on fuerte fails

Tags: openni, camera, ros-fuerte, rosmake, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to make the openni_camera-fuerte-devel package, but it fails. Here is the output:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['openni_camera-fuerte-devel']              
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/2010/bleona4/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130514-105639
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['openni_camera-fuerte-devel'] to:
['openni_camera-fuerte-devel']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild              
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                    
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole          
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs    
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib             
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs              
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                           
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs        
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                               
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> test_nodelet [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> polled_camera [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< polled_camera ROS_NOBUILD in package polled_camera     
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< test_nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package test_nodelet       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> camera_calibration_parsers [ make ]                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< camera_calibration_parsers ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_calibration_parsers
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> camera_info_manager [ make ]                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< camera_info_manager ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_info_manager
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> openni_camera-fuerte-devel [ make ]                    
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesenni_camera-fuerte-devel... [ 1 Active 25/26 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [rosbuild] Building package openni_camera-fuerte-devel
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
  -- checking for module 'libopenni'
  --   package 'libopenni' not found
  MSG: gencfg_cpp on:OpenNI.cfg
  Finding dependencies for /home/2010/bleona4/fuerte_workspace/openni_camera-fuerte-devel/cfg/OpenNI.cfg
  ***********************************************************************************
  load_module did not return. Unable to determine dependencies for file listed above.
  ***********************************************************************************
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/gendeps", line 64, in <module>
      imp.load_module("__main__", f, srcfile, ('.cfg', 'U', 1))
    File "/home/2010/bleona4/fuerte_workspace/openni_camera-fuerte-devel/cfg/OpenNI.cfg", line 4, in <module>
      import roslib; roslib.load_manifest(PACKAGE)
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
      sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 93, in _generate_python_path
      m = rospack.get_manifest(pkg)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 133, in get_manifest
      return self._load_manifest(name)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 172, in _load_manifest
      retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 164, in get_path
      raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
  rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: openni_camera
  ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
  ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
  ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
  ROS path [3]=/home/2010/bleona4/fuerte_workspace
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:66 (string):
    string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:87 (gencfg_cpp)
    CMakeLists.txt:18 (include)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package openni_camera-fuerte-devel written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/2010/bleona4/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130514-105639/openni_camera-fuerte-devel/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< openni_camera-fuerte-devel [FAIL] [ 4.38 seconds ]     
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package openni_camera-fuerte-devel. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 26 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/2010/bleona4/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130514-105639
```

How can I fix this problem? Unfortunately, I do not have sudo privileges to install the package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62701/rosmake-openni_camera-on-fuerte-fails/) by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 343 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-14**:
Alright, so I found a computer on which I had root access, so no need to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It needs to be in a folder named openni_camera not openni_camera-fuerte-devel. The package name is determined by the folder name.  Thus it cannot find openni_camera.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0